# WordPress Docent theme how to left align h2 blog title

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

This is how the page HTML looks like. It is `WordPress Docent theme`.

[image]

It is appearing in middle but I want to appear left aligned.

I tried:

```
align:left
width:100%
```

but no effect

Also, I tried:

```
align:left
width:max-content
```

This time it appears in the same line but bleeds out of this purple container.

How can I fix this so that it starts from left in one line and wrap it bigger than purple box?

Comment: Could you please share your HTML and CSS code?

Comment: I see `padding` being applied on both sides! The purple section indicates `padding`. So try to set the padding or padding-left to `0`.

Comment: It is WordPress, I don't know where CSS is located. Also, instead of messing up with themes' CSS, it will be great if I can write my own CSS for title h2 only.

Comment: Sure, you would need to set a child-them up then! It's very simple and lets you override the `css`!

Comment: Thanks, @Ruvee. It worked after reducing the padding to zero. Silly me I couldn't think of it. It was easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see `padding` being applied on both sides! The purple section indicates `padding`. So try to set the `padding` or `padding-left` to `0`. Like so:

```css
padding: 0;
```